# WordPress: Где изменить текст «Subscribe to our newsletter»?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

На странице оформления заказа (WooCommerce) есть чекбокс с лейблом «Subscribe to our newsletter», надо заменить это примерно на «Подписаться на рассылку».

В каком файле это изменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> чекбокс с лейблом «Subscribe to our newsletter», надо заменить это
>   примерно на «Подписаться на рассылку».
>
> В каком файле это изменить?

Это делается не в "файле", а в лангпаке того плагина или темы, в котором этот текст (при условии правильной локализации).
Это можно сделать напр с пом плагина https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

См так же
https://make.wordpress.org/meta/handbook/documentation/translations/
https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE/

Answer (score 1):

В WooCommerce такого функционала нет. Существует много правильных способов "вклиниться" в код WooCommerce - с помощью хуков в теме или плагинах, копированием и правкой шаблонов WooCommerce в дочерней теме. Поэтому круг поисков достаточно широк.

### Как найти источник текста

Отключайте плагины по очереди и смотрите, когда предложение подписаться исчезнет. Начинайте с плагинов подписки, вроде MailChimp, потом продолжите с плагинами - расширениями WooCommerce.

Если все плагины, кроме WooCommerce, отключены, а текст всё равно присутствует, то он добавлен в функциях или шаблонах темы. Смените тему на другую, и посмотрите, есть ли текст.

Если после отключения всех плагинов и смены темы текст всё равно присутствует, то привет разработчику сайта - он был глубоко неправ, добавив свой кастомный код в файлы плагина WooCommerce.

Так вы сузите круг поисков.

### Альтернативный способ поиска

Кликните правой кнопкой на label с искомым текстом, откройте dev tools. Посмотрите, какие классы имеют label и input чекбокса. Обычно названия легко соотнести с плагином, который выводит данный чекбокс.

### Радикальный способ поиска

Установите на локальный компьютер современную среду разработки, например, PhpStorm. Скачайте сайт целиком. PhpStorm проиндексирует все файлы, и любой текст в файлах можно будет найти мгновенно - быстрее, чем вы его вводите в окне глобального поиска (crtl+shift+F).

Скачивание сайта и индексация занимает определённое время, зато потом вы сможете находить всё, что угодно в кодах, за доли секунды.

### Как найти сам текст

Скачайте плагин или тему на локальный компьютер и запустите текстовый поиск по всем файлам php. Скорее всего, будет найден код вида

```
__( 'Subscribe to our newsletter', 'текстовый_домен' );
```

### Что с этим делать

`__()`  - это вызов функции перевода в текстовом домене плагина или темы. Вам нужно скачать перевод плагина или темы на русский (если они из официального репозитория WordPress), и дополнить перевод при необходимости. Для этого есть свободный редактор [poedit](https://poedit.net/). Полученный .mo файл нужно поместить в папку переводов темы или плагина, обычно это `/languages`.

Если в файле .php вы обнаружили код вида

```
<label ...>Subscribe to our newsletter</label>
```

то всё плохо, с разработчиком не повезло. Вам придётся править текст прямо в файле, загружать его на сервер, и навсегда забыть о возможности обновления этого плагина, потому что ваши правки будут затёрты при обновлении.

Если такой код в дочерней теме, то ничего страшного, можно править на месте. Обновления основной темы не затрагивают дочернюю.